# getting the address of the function?

Tags: c++

I'm writing this code and printing this line below shows me the address, how is that possible?

```
struct back
{
    static const int y = 7;
    static int f(int i = 0)
    {
        return i / 2;
    }
};
```

```
std::cout << back::f;      // 003A143D
```

Comment: Are you asking why you get the address instead of the return of the function?

Comment: Or are you asking how cout gets the address of the function?

Comment: He's asking why it prints the address instead of the return value

Comment: _"how is that possible?"_ Because a function decays to a pointer-to-function (much like how an array of `T` decays to a pointer-to-`T`).

Comment: The class static function `back::f` has an address in memory.  The code is printing that memory address.

Comment: You did not call the function. It converts to a pointer when you omit the (). To call the function you needed `std::cout << back::f();`

Comment: yes I didn't forget the (), but I want to know what's the theory behind that, why this is give me the pointer in other word the @ of that function? I want a documentation or something based on this answser please

Comment: What is the expected output from your point of view? Do you expect any output or compiler error?

Comment: The answer is "Yes". You are getting the address of the function.

Comment: Code exists in RAM just like data does. The name of the function, without parentheses, evaluates to the location, in memory, where that code is located.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/ojEpZD). What compiler and settings are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> getting the address of the function?

You can get the address of a function using the addressof operator `&`. The result (except in case of non-static member function) is a pointer to a function. The function lvalue can implicitly convert to a pointer to the function before lvalue to rvalue conversion. This implicit conversion is called decaying.

> printing this line below shows me the address, how is that possible?

This may be possible due to some language extension. The standard doesn't specify overloads for inserting function pointers to character streams. Standard conforming behaviour would be to print 1 because function pointer implicitly converts to bool which does have stream insertion overload, and the address of function is never null.

This is hardly ever intended behaviour which is why high quality compilers warn by default when function decays to a pointer.

Comment: thank you for this answer, but can you explain what decay is?

Comment: @Ope That's already explained. It's the implicit conversion from a function to a pointer to the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver pointer to function does not implicitly convert to `void*` (except potentially as language extension). Explicit reinterpretation is conditionally allowed.

Comment: Oh yeah.  I really wonder whats going on now as I can'r replicate the results.

Comment: @NathanOliver Only reasonable explanations that I can thing of: Old, pre-standard compiler (unlikely given that namespaces are used) or inclusion of some random library header that does naughty things.

Answer (score 0):

From eerorika's response, the printing of the class static function's address appears to be happenstance rather than by the standard.

You can override the behavior if you wish.  For example,

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {

struct back {
    static const int y = 7;
    static int f(int i = 0) {
        return i / 2;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, decltype(back::f)) {
    out << "baby ducks";
    return out;
}

} // anon

int main() {
    std::cout << back::f << "\n"; // Output: baby ducks
}
```

WARNING (from comment section): not a good idea to overload `<<` for `int(int)` since there is no user defined type involved.

Comment: I don't understand what's 'decltype' mean?

Comment: You overload an operator with arguments that are entirely fundamental (`int(int)`) or standard library type (`std::ostream&`). That's a no-no (I don't remember if it's UB, IFNDR or something else). Essentially because the standard reserves the right to introduce any such overload in a later version of the standard.

Comment: @eerorika, I didn't understand anything :(

Comment: @Ope That's OK. The comment is directed at Eljay.

Comment: @eerorika • I concur with your point about `int(int)`, since there is no user defined type involved.  I think this is in the realm of implicit undefined behavior, in the sense that the behavior of ostream'ing a function or (decayed) function pointer is not defined by the standard.  In that it prints an address at all I presume do to matching `void const*` output, however inadvertently.  Probably only works on platforms (as an implementation detail) that have same-ish data pointers and function pointers.